# C++ programming: getting an error or not according to the computer in use.

Tags: c++, operating-system

## Hello everyone,

Here a code in c++ programming:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Buffer {

    double* doubles;
    int size;

    public:

    Buffer(int size): size(size), doubles(new double[size]) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) doubles[i] = 0.0;
    }

    ~Buffer() {
        delete[] doubles;
    }

    void fill(double d) {
        Buffer newBuffer(size);
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) newBuffer.doubles [i] = d;
        this->doubles = newBuffer.doubles;
    }

    void print() const {
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) cout << doubles[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

};

int main() {
     Buffer b1(5); b1.print();
     Buffer b2(5); b2.fill(12.34); b2.print();
}`
```

This code is not supposed to run without exception.
Indeed, when my teacher run it (with his computer) he gets the next error:
*** Error in a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop):
0x0000000001178c90 ***.
Nevertheless, when I run it (with my computer) I don't get any error, and the code run without any exception.

I post a screen-shot of my terminal after running the code: 
[Screen-shot of the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcp2.png)

As you can see in the screen-shot, to run the code, I use the clang compiler (my teacher too), with the c++11, 14, and 17 versions.
Thus, my problem doesn't seem to be a c++ version's problem.
Adding the fact that I use Linux over Ubuntu, and my teacher too, it's probably not a operating-system's problem.

I'm very interested to know what is the reason of such a result ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: C++ doesn't normally throw exceptions for programming errors. You can't expect consistent and/or sensible behaviour for a double free.

Comment: The statement `this->doubles = newBuffer.doubles` in `fill()` causes both objects (`*this` and `newBuffer`) to have the same value of the `doubles` member.   This means, when the two objects are destroyed, the destructor does `delete [] doubles` on the same pointer more than once.    That is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since you are double-freeing the memory, you are invoking undefined behavior. The code, that invokes undefined behavior, can do anything at all, including, but not limited to: seeming to work fine, crashing, or formatting your hard drive.

Comment: *This code is not supposed to run without exception.* Yes, it does, since no exception will be thrown. Rather, a run-time error may occur from the run-time environment.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Why this code triggers double free? Or why it doesn't always trigger double free?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
The question i'm asking to is why does the code seems to normally run in my computer but get a run-time exception in my teacher's computer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are these two lines:

```
Buffer newBuffer(size);
...
this->doubles = newBuffer.doubles;
```

The first line creates a new `Buffer` object. The second line makes `this->double` point to the same memory that `newBuffer.doubles` is pointing to. That is, you have *two separate pointers* both pointing *to the very same memory*.

Now when that's done, the `newBuffer` object goes out of scope and is destructed. And the destructor will free the memory that both `this->doubles` and `newBuffer.doubles` is pointing to. That memory is no longer available to your application, using it in any way leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This includes both the printing *and* more specifically the deletion of the memory a *second* time in the destructor.

The simplest way to solve your problem is to realize that you don't *need* the temporary `newBuffer` object, you can just intitialize `this->doubles[i]` directly in the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) this->doubles [i] = d;
```

---

As for why it sometimes seems to work, it's because one of the possible behaviors of UB ([Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) is to seemingly work fine. Other times it might cause a crash or other weird behavior in seemingly unrelated parts of your program.

Comment: You don't even need that `this->` there.

Comment: Upped. Your explanation is so much better than mine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
How a Undefined Behavior may be detected if (like in my case) the code work fine?
And is this part of chance (to have the code run or not) may be a big issue for a programmer ?

Comment: @SamuelBismuth A good start is to always build with extra warnings enabled, as the compiler might be able to detect these issues. But since the compiler can't always do that, use of *static analysis tools* (also known as *linters*) are also useful. For critical code one should also employ code-review where one (or preferably more) people look at your code to see if it's good or makes sense. But worst case scenario is that UB sometimes isn't detected for years, even in bit commercial programs.

Comment: I get it.
Thanks you for your time, it was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw is in `fill`. You create a new `Buffer` object called `newBuffer`, and then trash the `doubles` in `this` (that actually causes a *memory leak*). `newBuffer` will delete its buffer when it goes out of scope at the end of `fill`, and so will the destructor called in `main` when `b2` goes out of scope!

That's *undefined behaviour*: `delete[]` is called twice on the same pointer. **Boom**.

The best thing to do by a country mile is to use a `std::vector<double>` as the class member. Having bare pointers as class members is a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your program constitutes what is known as [**undefined behaviour**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (for the obvious reasons pointed out in other answers), when the run-time **behaviour is unpredictable**.

Hence the outcome when running the code on different machines, with different compilers, at different times, by different people, ... may well be quite different, with a crash (*double free or corruption*) being the most benign (in contrast to running w/o apparent error).

Of course, undefined behaviour **should be avoided** like the plague. Unfortunately, this is harder said than done, as there are no reliable tools to detect all of it. Many programmers don't even know what constitutes undefined behaviour and what not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is code with an unpredictable behavior a big problem or is programmer can easily detect it ?

Comment: I consider code with undefined behavior, hence unpredictable behavior, to be a big problem which can be very difficult to detect.  There are tools, such as valgrind and enabling all compiler warnings, which can help detect these otherwise hard to notice problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your fill function is causing a memory leak and assigning a pointer that is about to be invalidated to your array.

You create a new buffer with a new array, fill that with some values, then you reassign the pointer of your old buffer (losing track of some memory - memory leak). After that, the new buffer goes out of scope so the destructor is called, deleting the memory of both the old and new buffers. And now you call print on memory that is not yours, hence you corrupt the heap. And THEN on top of it all, you try to free it again, even though it's already been freed.

Why not just set the values in the current buffer without creating a temporary, that seems better in every aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fill` function leaks memory, which in turn trigers UB. You may experience wierd behavior, crash, no symptom or troubles in other programs due to memrory disorder. The exact observation depends on platform and chance.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the assignment operator to do a deep copy. This will solve your problem.